# Функционал граф. векторного редактора

Tags: c#

Нужно дополнить простой существующий граф. редактор новым функционалом: сохранение и загрузка фигур в векторном представлении.
Что мог иметь в виду преподаватель, говоря "Архитектура должна предусматривать расширение (учет новых форматов)" ?

Comment: В книге Рихтера CLR via C# (обязательна к прочтению каждым дотнетчиком) приведён пример плагинной системы. Именно так можно добавлять расширения. Рекомендую.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Если текст в скобочках это ваше предположение:**

Возможно он имел ввиду разных форматов, а возможно и разных фигур в рамках одного формата. А возможно что-то совершенно другое, например разные варианты компановки файла или разные варианты разметки файла в рамках одного формата.

Мы не можем это знать, лучше всего у него и спросить что он имеет ввиду.

**Если же это слова преподавателя:**

Тогда означает что у вас должны быть классы и интерфейсы устроены таким образом что бы легко можно было добавить сохранение или импорт из разных форматов.

Например это может быть так:

Интерфейс:

```
IFormatSaver
  void SaveGraphics(Graphics graphics, string fileName);
```

Классы:

```
SVGSaver : IFormatSaver
VMLSaver : IFormatSaver
```

Наличие конфигурации разных видов Save-еров в файле настроек или через код, подключение и добавление...

Comment: поможет ли информация о том, что фигур всего три: эллипс, линия и прямоугольник?
сдается мне, он имеет в виду форматы хранения, а если это так, то что значит учет новых?

Comment: @Vanya Belyaev я добавил информацию.

Comment: понял, кроме последнего момента, а именно "Наличие конфигурации разных видов Save-еров в файле настроек или через код, подключение и добавление..."

Comment: @Vanya Belyaev возможно делать эти сейверы (модули) отдельно подключаемыми в проект, а какие именно модули подключать будет сказано в настройках. Но это, думаю не относится к вашему проекту, я говорил в общем про расширяемость и модульность.

Comment: большое спасибо, пример с интерфейсом помог понять более-менее...это курсовая такая)

Comment: @Vanya Belyaev Суть такая, вам надо продумать архитектуру, так что бы добавление нового сейвера, импорта было как нечто уже подготовленное системой, чем то что надо вручную везде прописывать и прокидывать.

Comment: @ Дмитрий Полянин благодарю!